# Saving image in local file system using node.js

Tags: node.js, image, axios, fs

I was working on a simple code to download missing images from a site and save it in the local system, given its complete URL. I am able to get the data in binary format as response and also I am able to save it properly. But when I try to open the image it shows the format is not supported by the system. I tried to save some js and css file and they are being saved properly and I am able to view them as well. But I am having problem with all the image formats.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
try {
  response = await axios.get(domain + pathOfFile);
  console.log(response);
  fs.writeFile(localBasePath + pathOfFile, response.data, "binary", (error) => {
    if (error) console.log("error while writting file", error.message);
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error in getting response", error.message);
}
```

**domian**: contains the base domain of the site
**pathOfFile**: contains the path of file on that domain
**localBasePath**: the base folder where I need to store the image
I even tried to store the response in a buffer and then tried to save the image, but still I am facing the same problem.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `responseEncoding` while calling `axios.get` method.

Change your line to:

```
response = await axios.get(domain + pathOfFile, {responseEncoding: "binary"});
```